# find the value of $\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{f(x)} {1+e^x} dx $?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> Let  $a$  be  a   postive  real number. If $f$  is  a continious  and even function  defined on the interval $[-a,a]$, then find the value of   $$\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{f(x)} {1+e^x} dx. $$

My answer  is :
$$2 \int_{0}^{a} \frac{f(x)} {1+e^x} dx $$ because $\int_{-a}^{a}  =  2\int_{0}^{a}$.

Is it correct??

any hints/solution  will  be  appreciated

Comment: Nope.  $(1 + e^x)$ is not even...  If instead you had $(1 + e^{|x|})$ well then...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$
I = \int_0^a + \int_{-a}^0 \frac {f(x)}{1+\mathrm e^x} \,\mathrm dx = \int_0^a \frac {f(x)\,\mathrm dx}{1+\mathrm e^x} + \int_0^a \frac {f(x)\, \mathrm dx}{1 + \mathrm e^{-x}} = \int_0^a \frac {f(x)(1 + \mathrm e^x)}{\mathrm e^x + 1}\,\mathrm dx = \int_0^a f. 
$$

Comment: thanks u ..@Xbh

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help.